Error Tagging in Corpus from English Language Learners
Is there anyone here with experience using the Louvain Error Tagging system (ideally, on English text in an L2 corpus?) I'm trying to learn it and would love to have someone to bounce questions and ideas off of. Thanks so much!

This is not the kind of question we deal with here as it is asking for help. Why not try the Chat? Upper right corner, last icon. You'll see it.

Thank you, Lambie, for the explanation and advice. Unfortunately, I am not able to participate in the Chat, as I do not have enough reputation points yet. But I will keep this in mind for the future.

Oops, didn't know that. A drawback, as far as I'm concerned. In any case, read the Help section and the types of questions one should ask. That is also a good idea.

Yes, thank you. I won't ask questions like this here in the future.
